# How to filter list results in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am trying to 'filter' out a result which is in a list format using Java. The purpose of this piece of code is to display all models of a car brand by using the car make as a filter parameter. So for example, list all models whereby make == BMW. Here are the relevant snippets of code:

```
public String getMake() {
    return make;
}


public void setMake(String value) {
    this.make = value;
}


public String getModel() {
    return model;
}


public void setModel(String value) {
    this.model = value;
}

public String ListMake(List thelist) {
    String listmake = "<ul>";
    if (thelist == theCarList) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < thelist.size(); i++) {
            Car curCar = (Car) thelist.get(i); 
            listmake = listmake + "<li>" + (curCar.getModel() + "</li>"); 
        }
    }

    listmake += "</ul>";
    System.out.println("URL = " + URL);
    tooltipstring = readwebsite(URL);
    String html = "<html>" + tooltipstring + "</html>";
    Myface.setmytooltip(html);
    Myface.setmyinfobox(URL2);

    return listmake;
}
```

The issue i am having is that i am unable to display all models (curCar.getModel()) based on their make.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have:

```
if (thelist == theCarList) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < thelist.size(); i++) {
        Car curCar = (Car) thelist.get(i); 
        listmake = listmake + "<li>" + (curCar.getModel() + "</li>"); 
    }
}
```

but, to only show the certain makes of lets say BMW, you would need to include

```
if (thelist == theCarList) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < thelist.size(); i++) {
        Car curCar = (Car) thelist.get(i); 

        if(curCar.getMake().equals("BMW"){ //THIS IS THE LINE YOU ARE MISSING

            listmake = listmake + "<li>" + (curCar.getModel() + "</li>"); 
        }
    }
}
```

by using this new if statement you are ensuring that the make of the car is what you specify

(you could also take in the name of the make as a parameter)

-Kore

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought it was something along those lines but didn't know how to implement it.

Comment: @AbdulNaji if this helped and solved your solution, could you accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left to my solution.